# Access not configured error while calling blogger API

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, blogger

I am trying to fetch a blog details using jQuery and JSON. I have also set up an API key (for browser application)to access the blog but my API key is not working properly.Please suggest how to configure it properly.

Code:

```
<!Doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>My Page</title> 

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <script>

        var url =  'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/',
            apikey = '/posts?key=API_KEY',
            blogId = '4011997376355783864';


            $.ajax({

                url: url +blogId+apikey,

                dataType: "jsonp",

                success  : function(data){

                    console.log(data);
                },
                error   :function(request, error){
                    alert('error');
                }

            });


        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Error :

```
error: Objectcode: 403
errors: Array[1]
message: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
```

Key details :

[image: API Details]

Comment: Do not make your API key public.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. I just click "Edit allowed referers" and empty the input field.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an Android application that I want to connect with some Blogger' blogs and of course, I needed access to Blogger API v3. I had the same error in the request:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}
```

I had created an API Key for the application (**Android key**) and I think that I was doing in the right way but that errors pushed me every time I tried until I created another API Key type (**server key or browser key**) and magic happened.

I did not understand the logic until now but I seriously think that things like that can be described in the official docs.